# php echo filenames in a directory?

Tags: php, file

I am using the following php code to echo out the names (and extensions) of all the files in a folder.

This works fine and I am producing the results in a table like so:

code:

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("data/uploads/");
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
echo '<table><tr><td><p>' . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n" . '</p></td><td><p>Existing File</p></td><td><p>Delete</p></td></tr><tr></tr></table>';
 }?>
```

result:

```
.                     Existing File         Delete
..                    Existing File         Delete
Filename1.jp          Existing File         Delete
Filename2.jp          Existing File         Delete
Filename3.jp          Existing File         Delete
```

The problem is in my results I am also getting those weird dots at the top. I do not know why these are being shown as I only have 3 files in the directory and don't know where the dots have come from?

Can anyone please help with this? thanks

Comment: The 'strange dots' are in fact pointers to current directory and the previous directory. On most file systems you can do something like `cd ..` to go up one directory, and thats why functions like glob includes these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Condition to check that is it file or not.. try this code

```
if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {  // add this condition
    echo '<table><tr><td><p>' . $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n" . '</p></td><td><p>Existing File</p></td><td><p>Delete</p></td></tr><tr></tr></table>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add condition and check if it is . or .. if it satisfies the condition continue your looop